# Finding legacy calls within ASP.NET DLLs

Tags: .net, dll, legacy

I have an ASP.NET web application that leverages 5 DLLs. This web application and its DLLs are all very old, and occasionally we find some deprecated call or something that has been broken over time. Currently I am getting this error, which I believe is a .NET active directory call which no longer is present in the latest version.

> Method not found: 'System.String System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_Password()'.Method not found: 'System.String System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_Password()'.

The problem is that call is not present in visible code; It must be coming from one of the DLLs. I do not have access to the source code for all the DLLs. Is there an easy way to search within these DLLs to identify which one the problem is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)** to load up these DLLs and search for any calls you get errors for, it's a tremendously handy tool.

Comment: You have been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflector to browse the source code.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

And the example is actually a read only property.
you are looking for

```
string s = System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Password;
```